Hugging Face InstructorEmbedding _load_sbert_model, unexpected keyword argument 'token'
When trying to deploy the RAG system containing the Python function below
def create_or_get_vector_store(chunks: list) -> FAISS:
    """
    Funzione per creare o caricare il database vettoriale dalla memoria locale.

    Returns:
        FAISS: Vector store
    """

    # Automatically choose device: CUDA if available, otherwise CPU
    device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

    # Initialize HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings with the chosen device
    embeddings = HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings(
        query_instruction="Represent the query for retrieval: ",
        model_name="hkunlp/instructor-large",  # Example model name
        model_kwargs={'device': device}, 
        encode_kwargs={'normalize_embeddings': True}  # Optional: to normalize the embeddings
    )

    # Check if the vector store exists; if not, create it
    if not os.path.exists("./db"):
        print("CREATING DB")
        # Create the FAISS vector store from the documents (chunks)
        vectorstore = FAISS.from_documents(chunks, embeddings)
        # Save the vector store locally
        vectorstore.save_local("./db")
    else:
        print("LOADING DB")
        # Load the pre-existing vector store
        vectorstore = FAISS.load_local("./db", embeddings)

    return vectorstore

I get an error saying:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Lucrezia\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\LangChain\.venv\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\exec_code.py", line 88, in exec_func_with_error_handling
result = func()
>              ^^^^^^
File "c:\Users\Lucrezia\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\LangChain\.venv\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 579, in code_to_exec
exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\Lucrezia\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\LangChain\main2.py", line 209, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\Lucrezia\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\LangChain\main2.py", line 177, in main
st.session_state.vector_store = create_or_get_vector_store(chunks)
>                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Lucrezia\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\LangChain\main2.py", line 82, in create_or_get_vector_store
embeddings = HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings(
>                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "c:\Users\Lucrezia\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\LangChain\.venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain_community\embeddings\huggingface.py", line 190, in __init__
self.client = INSTRUCTOR(
>                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
File "c:\Users\Lucrezia\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\LangChain\.venv\Lib\site-packages\sentence_transformers\SentenceTransformer.py", line 308, in __init__
modules, self.module_kwargs = self._load_sbert_model(
>                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: INSTRUCTOR._load_sbert_model() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'
2024-11-30 12:18:35.371 Examining the path of torch.classes raised: Tried to instantiate class '__path__._path', but it does not exist! Ensure that it is registered via torch::class_

I checked the documentation on LangChain and Hugging Face but no solution was found.
The machine has sentence-transformers Version: 3.3.1, langchain-0.3.9 langchain-core-0.3.21 langsmith-0.1.147.
